# Exporting InnerHTML as HTML file - Inline CSS Style Hash Issue

Tags: javascript, css, innerhtml

When exporting the data, the process is bombing out on the # symbol used for colour codes. I need these to be inline styles as the code will be used as a signature file.

I'm using the following JS;

```
function downloadSignature() {
    var a = document.body.appendChild(
    document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = "signature.html";
    a.href = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + document.getElementById("signature").innerHTML;
    a.click();
}
```

Here's an example line where the export process fails;

```
<tr>

    <td style="font-family:Arial,serif;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold;color:#d4121e;padding-bottom: 6px;">John Smith</td>

</tr>
```

Everything is fine till the # - does anyone know why this might be? Is the encoding method for the file at fault? I've tried plain/html and base64, neither seem to help.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the initial question, but a work around is of course just to use rgb.

Comment: works fine for me

Comment: I can reproduce this. One way to solve this is to have the server send the signature, instead of using JavaScript to "simulate" a download.